# Lagrange's theorem in number theory

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to understand proof of Lagrange's theorem in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(number_theory)).

In proof it says:

> we can compute $g(k)$ either directly, i.e. by plugging in (the
>   residue class of) $k$ and performing arithmetic in $\textstyle
> > \mathbb{Z}/p,$ or by reducing $f(k) \mod p.$

I'm wondering what is $\mathbb{Z}/p,$ what does it mean to *perform arithmetic in* $\mathbb{Z}/p$ and *reducing* $f(k) \mod p?$ Thanks.

Though *reducing* $f(k) \mod p$ probably is just taking $f(k) \mod p.$

Maybe with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ they mean $\mathbb{Z}_p?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is common for the ring of residue classes modulo $p$. It derives from the more detailed notation  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, which is a special instance of the notation used for the quotient of a ring modulo an ideal, $R/I$, or also of a group modulo a (normal) subgroup, $G/H$.

An alternative notation is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, as you suspect; however some people dislike this notation as it is also used for the ring of $p$-adic integers, which is something quite different.

You assumption about "reducing" is correct, too.